# ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78' Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2

I know this is probably a duplicate  of another question but i've searched all over and tried everything but it still seems to be giving me the same error of.We recently migrated from SQL SERVER 2005 to 2008 .After migration We are facing this Problem.I am using classic ASP,SQL and HTML.

Below is My SQL SERVER 2008 PROCEDURE. I noticed one strange thing after migration that in my procedure there are red under lines for temproary table 
and warning "invalid object " .But when I ran this procedure Manually it return me 6 records

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ASH_WEB_S] @GMID VARCHAR(10), @DIR_YR CHAR(4)
AS

   SET NOCOUNT ON

   SELECT DIV_MGR_ID,
   '' DMGR_LST_NM,
   MGR_ID,
   ' ' MGR_LST_NM,
   SUM(REV_ASG) TOT_ASG,
   SUM(REV_HDL) TOT_SVC,
   SUM(REV_SLD) CORE_TOT_SLD
   INTO #S_GM_AUDIT
   FROM
   RPT_ASH
   WHERE
   DIV_MGR_ID = @GMID
   GROUP BY
   DIV_MGR_ID,
   MGR_ID

   UPDATE #S_GM_AUDIT
   SET DMGR_LST_NM = D.LST_NM,
   MGR_LST_NM = M.LST_NM
   FROM #S_GM_AUDIT A, ASM M, DSM D
   WHERE A.MGR_ID = M.MGR_ID AND
   A.DIV_MGR_ID = D.DIV_MGR_ID AND
   M.AFF_CD = 'S' AND D.AFF_CD = 'S'

   BACKUP LOG FASTRACK TO DISK='NUL:'

   SELECT * FROM #S_GM_AUDIT

   DROP TABLE #S_GM_AUDIT
```

This is the line that is giving the error when calling this procedure;

```
While NOT ors.EOF
```

Below is the ASP code

```
<% Option Explicit                                                      
Dim DbObj, SQL, oRs, intRowColor, FNM, GMID, DIR_YR, AFF_CD, YEAR_IND   
FNM = Request.QueryString("FNM")                                        
GMID = Request.QueryString("GMID")                                      
DIR_YR = Request.QueryString("DIR_YR")                                  
AFF_CD = Request.QueryString("AFF")                                     
YEAR_IND = Request.QueryString("YEAR_IND")                              
%>                                                                      
<% Server.ScriptTimeout = 300 %>                                        
<head>                                                                  
<meta NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0">           
</head>                                                                 
<%                                                                      
 IF AFF_CD = "P" THEN
IF YEAR_IND = "N" THEN
    SQL = "SP_ASH_WEB_S 'P', '" & GMID & "', '" & DIR_YR & "'"
ELSE
    SQL = "SP_ASH_WEB_S'P', '" & GMID & "', '" & DIR_YR & "'"
END IF                                                                
END IF                                                                  
OpenConnection()                                                        
Set oRs = DbObj.Execute(SQL)                                            
 %>                                                                      
 <form method="get">                                                     
 <table BORDER="0" WIDTH="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">         
 <%                                                                      
 dim totasg,totsvc,coretotsld,grandtotasg,grandtotsvc,grandcoretotsld    
 WHILE NOT oRs.EOF  
 totasg = oRs.Fields("tot_asg")
 totsvc = oRs.Fields("tot_svc")
 coretotsld = oRs.Fields("core_tot_sld")
 grandtotasg = grandtotasg + totasg
 grandtotsvc = grandtotsvc + totsvc
 grandcoretotsld = grandcoretotsld + coretotsld
 if intRowColor = "0" then 
 intRowColor = "1"
```

Here is Definition Of my `OpenConnection()` function:

```
Function OpenConnection()

Set DbObj = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

DbObj.Open "DATABASE=Fastrack;Provider=SQLOLEDB;

DataSource=ASHISH\ASHISH;UID=ashish;PWD=ashish;"

End Function

Function CloseConnection()

DbObj.Close()

set DbObj = nothing

End function
```

Comment: Right, so you tried everything? Even all the examples that show that this type of code is going to cause you problems, especially vunerable to SQL Injection. I guess you didn't try very much after all, I at least expected an example using `ADODB.Command`.

Comment: You've got a typo here for starters..un-terminated string `SQL = "SP_CEO_N_GMGR_CUS_AUDIT_WEB_P '" & GMID & "', '" & DIR_YR & "` should be `SQL = "SP_CEO_N_GMGR_CUS_AUDIT_WEB_P '" & GMID & "', '" & DIR_YR & "'"` but I wouldn't suggest using that.

Comment: Sorry Lankymart you are right ,Actually there are lots of IF so i deleted all those to keep one to not confuse readers with this ,Doing that it get deleted

Comment: I assume `OpenConnection()` does something like instantiate the `DbObj` object variable, can you post it's definition to the question? Are you sure that the connection is being correctly established? *(i.e. `Open()` method)*

Comment: @Lankymart I am an ETL developer ,this is an old application in our project which is just migrated .I am not an expert in ASP classic neither as in SQL server as such .I was looking error of SQL server which is saying invalid object to temproary tables .My all focus was on correcting the SQL procedure .i will  try using ADODB.command but i think for that i need to change whole this code

Comment: Problem is I can't help you if you can't give me the minimum which in this case would be the `OpenConnection()` function that isn't built into Classic ASP that is a user defined function will have a definition somewhere `Function OpenConnection() ... End Function` without seeing that I'm still just guessing.

Comment: @Lankymart i have find out some how those Definition written in DBconnect File

Comment: Neither of those stored procedures (`SP_CEO_N_GM_CNV_AUDIT_WEB` and `SP_GMGR_AUDIT_WEB`) in the `If` statement correspond to the stored procedure you have posted (`SP_ASH_WEB_S`), are you sure this is the right code?

Comment: Yes its right code SP_CEO_N_GM_CNV_AUDIT_WEB and SP_GMGR_AUDIT_WEB ,SP_ASH_WEB_S are same almost let me correct it for user so they do not get confuse

Comment: First thing I would is debug that the `SQL` being passed into `Set oRs = DbObj.Execute(SQL)` is correct by adding a line before that line that reads `Response.Write "SQL: " & SQL` and see what is returned on the page should be a valid SQL string you can copy and paste directly into SSMS and run as a test.

Comment: @Lankymart its just giving me procedure Nmae nothing else  SP_ASH_WEB_S '115573 ', '2017'

Comment: Yes to check the values are getting populated correctly so can you paste `SP_ASH_WEB_S '115573 ', '2017'` into SSMS and execute it? Do you get a result?

Comment: @Lankymart Any suggestion

Comment: If that is all the relevant code then no there is nothing obvious that springs out at me usually that error is because the `ADODB.Recordset` comes back in a `adStateClosed` state because no query has been returned rather then an `adStateOpen` empty recordset. It's likely that it's seeing one of the commands in the stored procedure as a Closed Recordset *(which `SET NOCOUNT ON` is suppose to suppress)*. You could try checking for more recordsets, under the `Execute()` plave the following to move to the next recordset object if one exists `Set oRs = oRs.NextRecordset()`.

Comment: It might be the `BACKUP LOG` command I bet it's outputting to the print buffer *(success messages etc)* and ADO is interpreting that as a Closed Recordset object.

Comment: Yes Lankymart it is this statement as I discuss with my colleague who migrated it to SQL server 2008 ,said that she replaced DUMP TRANSACTION FASTRACK WITH NO_LOG with BACKUP LOG statement because DUMP transaction is not supported in SQL SERVER 2005 .is there any alternative for the statement DUMP TRANSACTION FASTRACK WITH NO_LOG